# Запрос на удаление информации (alert, confirm)

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, как грамотно реализовать, например, запрос на удаление информации? Есть иконка с ссылкой `?do=edit&id=34`. Хотел повесить событие click на эту ссылку, он игнорирует и сразу переходит по ней.

Comment: Не работает. Но логику примерно понял, буду разбаираться. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="?remove" onclick="return (confirm('Удалить?'));">[X]</a>
```

Если событие onclick возвращает false, дальнейшие действия не выполняются. Если true или void (ничего т.е.), происходит переход по ссылке.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var curLink = false; </script>
<a href="?remove" onclick="curLink=this;$.jqDialog.confirm('Удалить?',function(){document.location.href=curLink.href;},function(){});return false;">[X]</a>
```

Как-то так навскидку.

В отдельном файле:

```
var advConfirmLink = '';
function advancedConfirm(link, text) {
  advConfirmLink = link.href;
  $.jqDialog.confirm(
    text,
    function(){document.location.href=advConfirmLink;},
    function(){});
  return false;
  }
```

Использование:

```
<a href="?remove" onclick="return advancedConfirm(this, 'Удалить?');">[X]</a>
```

Comment: Это я знаю. А как быть с этим плагином? http://kailashnadh.name/code/jqdialog/

Comment: Замечательно! И ещё вопросик. Как это можно вынести в функцию в отдельный файл и в onclick её вызвать? Просто подобных ссылок то много и все на разных страницах.

Comment: А я прошу прощения, не везде переменную заменил. теперь должно.